# Questions about the Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

1: When it says 15 requests per 15 minute window, does this really mean I can only send 15 requests per 15 minutes?

2: Do I really need to set up a Twitter bot to send basic requests like getting a list of a user's followers? Is there a way to get the data through a URL, like in most web APIs? I'm making software that will be used by other people, so it can't have a bot auth token in the code.

I know I'm pretty much asking if what it blatantly says is true, but I'm just having trouble believing that the Twitter API is really this bad.

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds like you are specifically asking about the friends and followers endpoints. Yes, this is limited to 15 requests in a 15 minute window. Other endpoints / features have different rate limits.
2. The Twitter API requires authentication. You do not need to set up a "bot", but you will need a registered Twitter developer account, and a Twitter app, in order to use the API. If your app will be used by other people, you would need to implement Sign-in with Twitter to enable them to authenticate with your app; you can then store their access token (until or unless they revoke it) to make requests on their behalf. This is pretty standard for any multi-user web app.